# How to disable a link_to unless condition is met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
=link_to movies_path do
    <i class = "fa fa-caret-left"></i>
```

This code works and displays the awesome text as a button just how I want it to. I only want the button to display under a certain prama. I tried using link_to_if but then it only displays the link text as a button.

```
=link_to_if 0, movies_path do
    <i class = "fa fa-caret-left"></i>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`link_to_if`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) handles passed arguments differently than [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

A block passed to `link_to` is rendered nested into the `<a>` tag. Whereas a block passed to `link_to_if` is rendered as an alternative when the condition is not meet. Therefore you cannot use `link_to_if` with a block like you did before.

Just use an ordinary `if` instead:

```
- if condition
  = link_to movies_path do
    %i.fa.fa-caret-left
```